# BCH decoding example

Tags: coding-theory

> Let $\alpha $ be a root of $X^4 + X + 1$, and let C be the BCH code of length 15 with defining set the first four powers of $\alpha $. Determine the error position of the following received word: $1+X^6 + X^7 + X^8$.

I have calculated that the generator polynomial for C is $f(x) = X^8 + X^7 + X^6 + X^4 + 1$. So it seems obvious that there is one error, which occurs at $X^4$. However when I try to get this result algorithmically, it doesn't seem to work.

I am using the following algorithm:
Let $\sigma(X)$ be the error locator polynomial = $\prod_{i\in \xi}(1-\alpha^iX)$, where $\xi $ are the indices of the errors. Let t be the number of errors we can correct. Then $\sigma(X)\sum_{j=1}^{2t} r(\alpha^i)X^j \equiv w(X)$, where r(X) is the polynomial we received, and w(X) has degree less than or equal to t.

So we compute the product, and by noting that powers of X greater than t must be zero, we can calculate $\sigma(X)$.

However when I actually do the calculation, I get

$\sigma(X)\sum_{j=1}^{2t} r(\alpha^i)X^j = \sigma(X)[(\alpha+1)X + (\alpha^2+1)X^2 + (1+\alpha + \alpha^2 + \alpha^3)X^3 + \alpha X^4]$.

Plugging in the expected form of the answer $\sigma(X) = (1+(\alpha+1)X)$ doesn't seem to work, and I can't see why.

EDIT NOTE: This comes from my lecture notes not a book, so the formula itself may be wrong. If anyone knows where this occurs in the literature, that would also be appreciated.

Comment: The error locator polynomial $\sigma(X)$ is _not_ $\prod_{i=1}^{2t}(1-\alpha^iX)$ as you have defined it to be.  Note that _your_ $\sigma(X)$ is the _same_ fixed degree $2t$ polynomial regardless of what the actual errors might be and where they might be located, and hence is not helpful in the least  in _locating_ the errors.  -1 pending your edit (after _very carefully_ reading your textbook and double-checking that what it says has been correctly copied into your question) to make this a more reasonable question.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I have edited the question to what I believe it should be. It is taken from lecture notes though, not from a textbook, so I have just put in what seems like a reasonable guess. I was unable to find the formula online, partly as I don't know if it has a name or not.

Comment: OK, downvote removed.  Now try to express field elements as powers of $\alpha$ rather than polynomials in $\alpha$ so that instead of $(\alpha+1)X$ you write $\alpha^4X$ and similarly for the other terms,

Comment: If I do that then the leading term (ie the coefficient of $X^5$) is $\alpha^5$, which does not equal zero. In fact, whenever I represent it in that form, the leading term will always be non-zero, since we are in an integral domain. I don't understand how it is then possible to get zero.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I've figured out what the answer is by trying a load of examples. I think that the equation should read:

$\sigma(X)\sum_{j=1}^{2t} r(\alpha^i)X^j \equiv w(X) \mod X^{2t+1}$.

This then gives the right answer for all of the examples I've tried. Adding in this mod also seems to be the only way to remove the highest order term.

Comment: The equation _is  supposed_ to read $\sigma(X)\sum_{j=1}^{2t} r(\alpha^j)X^j \equiv w(X) \bmod X^{2t+1}$ and not $\sigma(X)\sum_{j=1}^{2t} r(\alpha^j)X^j = w(X)$ the way you had it in your question. If your book has the latter form, your book is wrong. In BCH decoding, when there are $t$ or fewer errors, w(x) is of degree $< e$ where $e$ is the actual number of errors, and the polynomial  $\sigma(X)\sum_{j=1}^{2t} r(\alpha^j)X^j$ has zeros in the middle, specifically, the coefficients of $X^e, X^{e+1}, \ldots, X^{2t}$ are all zero, and higher degree terms are again nonzero (e.g. your $X^5$).